# How to use && jumping lines in CMD

Tags: cmd.exe

In windows cmd, how do I write to do one command after the other is finished (not at the same time), by using && but not in same line of the command.

Example: command1 && command2 && command3 will do command1, when finished, will do command2, when finish will do command3.

But:

command1 && command2 && command3

Is in a same line.

I would like to write it jumping lines like this:

command1

&&

command2

&&

command3

So it dont get messy... However it isnt working.

Is there a way to write this && skiping the lines for a better visual effect?

Thanks

Comment: That's not possible, also why would you aim readability there. Why not just type your commands in a batch file and execute it?

Comment: Hello Máté, I am new to it, didnt know about batch file, will check about it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break lines using a caret `^`. The caret gets returned without a space for execution so you'll need a space on the next line. Example here:

```
command1 &&^
 command2 &&^
 command3
```

*note space before command 2 and 3.

Typically, you would write this in a notepad document and then save it as a `.bat` (batch file).